# multiple graphs pdf R

Tags: r, pdf-generation

I would like to print multiple graphs in one pdf file.  I know there has been a lot on this, but I would like to print different window/graph sizes for each page, i.e. first page a 8.5x11, second page 11x8.5 and so on.  I tried this:

```
pdf(file="Combined_Graphs.pdf",onefile=TRUE,bg="white",width=8.5,height=11)
hist(rnorm(100))
pdf(file="Combined_Graphs.pdf",onefile=TRUE,width=11, height=8.5, bg="white")
hist(rnorm(100,10,2),col="blue")
dev.off()
```

I must be using `onefile=TRUE` wrong as it only generates the last graphic before closing.  Is there a better way to size the graphic device without having to call the pdf function twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do cannot be done in R, i.e., you need to use external tools such as the PDF toolkit as suggested by Paul Hiemstra to combine separate PDF files with varying page dimensions (an alternative tool is [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/)).

If you set `onefile = TRUE` in your call to `pdf()`, each plot that is written to that PDF device will be printed on a separate page, yet with the same page dimensions. In your example, you open a first PDF device, write one plot to it, then you open a second PDF device, write a different plot to it, and then close the second PDF device but leave the first PDF device open. Since you use the same `file` argument for both `pdf()` calls, you might not notice that the first PDF device is still open. If you closed it, only the first plot would end up in `"Combined_Graphs.pdf"`.

Here is a modified version of your example that illustrates how PDF devices are opened, filled with content, and closed:

```
pdf(file = "foo.pdf", onefile = TRUE, width = 8.5, height = 11)
hist(rnorm(100))
hist(rnorm(100, 10, 2), col = "red")
pdf(file = "bar.pdf", width =11, height = 8.5)
hist(rnorm(100, 10, 2), col = "blue")
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 7):

What I would do is produce seperate PDF's and them combine them later. I use [the PDF toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for this. Wrapping this in an R function using a system call through `system` even makes it scriptable from R. The call to pdftk will look something like:

```
pdftk *pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

or in R:

```
system("pdftk *pdf cat output combined.pdf")  

combine_pdfs = function(path, output_pdf) {
  system(sprintf("pdftk %s/*pdf cat output %s"), path, output_pdf)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is awesome, works very well and I never have to use adobe acrobat again :)

Comment: You can do all kinds of neat stuff with pdftk. Running it from the command line makes it easy to script, e.g. cutting up pdf's that consist of sub-reports with unequal length.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please feel free to check the green tickmark.